# CSS background size using orientation

Tags: css, amazon-s3, orientation, exif

have an image uploaded to S3 here:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/buildsanctuary/images/1458083137.png

You can see that the browser is showing it in the correct orientation.

However, if you check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2oz06kv4/1/

The orientation is incorrect.

How can I remedy this?

The code for how im showing this image:

```
.profile-image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: @D3TXER Not all images are incorrect. Its a profile image so users are uploading whats ever they want.

Comment: Does the issue remain if you convert it to a JPEG and reupload it?